# Hiding nth child inside link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following HTML and JS

```
<div class = "tab-menu">
    <ul class = "tabs">
        <a><li>List item 1</li></a>
        <a><li>List item 2</li></a>
        <a><li>List item 3</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The list items are in the a tag so that the entire list item is clickable. Given certain conditions, I'm trying to use jQuery to hide certain list items. It worked fine before I wrapped them all in a tags, but now I can't get them to hide.

```
jQuery(".tab-menu .tabs > li:nth-child(3)").hide();
```

I've tried every variation I can think of to get the JS to recognize the list item it needs to hide, but I can't find it. Can I get some insight?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. It should be like `<li><a>List item 1</a></li>`, _ul_ element can only have _li_ as children

Comment: Your HTML is invalid -- the only valid **child** of a `ol` or `ul` is an `li`

Comment: To make the entire `li` clickable, use correct HTML and make the a elements `display: block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot have `<li>` tags inside `<a>` tags.

try doing this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

add the following css if you want the link to act like a block element

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start by moving your `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that your HTML is invalid (anchors must not be direct childNodes from `<ul>`), you would need to address the `anchor` nodes to make this work.

```
jQuery(".tab-menu .tabs > a:nth-child(3)").hide();
```

But anyway, that is just pure theory. Even if this might work, you need to fix the order of elements into `<li><a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have `li` tags inside `a` tags.
reverse will work there have look at below snippet.

```js
$(function(){
  jQuery(".tab-menu .tabs > li:nth-child(3)").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "tab-menu">
    <ul class = "tabs">
        <li><a>List item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>List item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>List item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> > as per w3.org permitted parent of li is => ul, ol and menu

here is reference [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-content-model) for w3 documentation

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery here. Once you've cleaned up your HTML syntax, you can hide items of the list using CSS like this:

```
ul > li:first-child {display: none;} /* hides first child */
ul > li:nth-child(2) {display: none;} /* hides the nth-child [in this case, the second child] */
ul > li:last-child {display: none;} /* hides the last child */
```